# Tensorflow's random.truncated_normal returns different results with the same seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, random-seed

The following lines are supposed to get the same result:

```
print (tf.random.truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=1234))
print (tf.random.truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=1234))
```

But I got:

```
tf.Tensor([-0.12297685 -0.76935077], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.37034193 1.3367208 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be intentional, see the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed). Specifically the "Examples" section.

What you need is `stateless_truncated_normal`:

```
print(tf.random.stateless_truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=[1234, 1]))
print(tf.random.stateless_truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=[1234, 1]))
```

Gives me

```
tf.Tensor([1.0721238  0.10303579], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.0721238  0.10303579], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Note: The seed needs to be two numbers here, I honestly don't know why (the docs don't say).

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow has two types of seeds the global and the operational - this is also why you need to pass two numbers to `stateless_truncated_normal` as *xdurch0* describes in his answer. Tensorflow combines these two seeds to generate a new one.

```
tf.random.truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=1234) # global seed #1 & operational 1234 -> Seed A
tf.random.truncated_normal(shape=[2],seed=1234) # global seed #2 & operational 1234 -> Seed B
```

There are multiple ways to tackle your problem. Set the global seed as well beforehand twice.
Work inside `@tf.functions` these kindof reset the global seed and have their own operational counters.
Or use `stateless_truncated_normal` as written in the other answer.

As already linked, in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed) it is described as well.